# How to wrap the newly input text into the following already-existed span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If user put something before wordx in contenteditable div, e.g. somthingwordx, since the newly added text "soemthing" was not wrapped into any existed span automatically, how do I know which span did user added text to and wrap it into that span using javascript?

Demo:

```
<div id="inputbox" style="border:1px solid lightgrey" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="1">word1</span>  <span id="2">word2</span>
  <span id="3">word3</span>  <span id="4">word4</span>  <span id="5">word5</span>  <span id="6">word6</span>  <span id="7">word7</span>  <span id="8">word8</span>  <span id="9">word9</span>  <span id="10">word10</span>  <span id="11">word11</span>  <span id="12">word12</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you need. Could you create a working demo with what you have tried?

Comment: bro i think it would be great if you can show what you have tried instead of just telling everyone your problem. u might be helped  better.

Comment: Thanks, I have only a little clue,working on it.

Comment: Don't use html tags in posts without posting them in code(with four spaces in the start, or wrapping in backticks(\`)). Otherwise, it won't show in the post. Just a limitation of HTML markup.

Comment: Also, is the `<span id="6>` missing doublequote above intentional?

Comment: @MohammadAnini: In future, please do not fix the code in the question, without checking with the OP first whether the typo is only on their question, or actually within their code as well. The typo you fix could well be the entire reason the question exists in the first place.

Comment: @cst1992 missing doublequote is not intentional, sorry for my typo. My difficulty was about how to know which span (1,2,3,4 or 5 etc) did user add text to using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now updated the code with a solution for you that is working. Check out the snippet or the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4xcxLt34/2/

Hope it will help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    $('#result > p').text($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputbox" style="border:1px solid lightgrey" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="1"> word1</span>
  <span id="2"> word2</span>
  <span id="3"> word3</span>
  <span id="4"> word4</span>
  <span id="5"> word5</span>
  <span id="6"> word6</span>
  <span id="7"> word7</span>
  <span id="8"> word8</span>
  <span id="9"> word9</span>
  <span id="10"> word10</span>
  <span id="11"> word11</span>
  <span id="12"> word12</span>
</div>
<div id='result'>
  <h3>
  This is the span that is changed:
  </h3>
  <p>

  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually my difficulty was how to detect where  user add text to. if user add text beofre word7, or 8, or 9 etc. , how do I detect which span is it using javascript?

Comment: @zoyb I have edited my code, so try to write something in the textbox and you will se that the word7 will change and under you see witch span that has bin affected.

Comment: @if you put some text **just before** a word, it can't be detected which span did it affected. any idea how to hack this? for example, type "a" **just before** word8, getting "aword8", DOMSubtreeModified can't detect which does it affect

Comment: Can you explain to me how your/the user is changing the span? I hope not through the HTML-fil because the there is no chance of detecting the edit.

Comment: I have now updated the code for you. Check out the snippet or the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4xcxLt34/

Comment: Thanks VERY much for the follow up. But it doesn't work if without <br> tag, as in my case. I'm now thinking of doing it in another way. the user's input would be wrapped in a span tag with a  special class (do you know how to achieve this?), then find if the special span being a child or sibling to other normal span, if being siblings, delete the special span and wrap the text into the follow sibling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109460/discussion-between-zorken17-and-zoyb).